# How to add an entry to ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, manytomanyfield, junction-table

I have the following models:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    cmt = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0) # vote_type is +1 for upvote & -1 for downvote

class Comment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='random')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True) # ForeignKey('User')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Vote', related_name='votes_table')
```

If I wasn't using the `through` keyword, I could have just added an element to votes field in Comment object (having uuid of `id`), like this: `Comment.objects.get(uuid=id).votes.add(some_user)`
But this won't work here, since I have to store a `vote_type` for each entry in `comments_votes` table. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the `Vote` instance as [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
Vote.objects.create(cmt=Comment.objects.get(uuid=id),
                    user=some_user, vote_type=1)
```

Comment: Why would `Vote(cmt=cmt, user=some_user, vote_type=1).save()` not work?